# Does trello search texts in comments

Tags: trello, comments

Does trello search texts in comments from the universal search-bar (the search bar at the left-top besides the Trello logo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't search comments, it only searches card titles and descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Not true anymore, it does search comments.

Use the command -> `comment:your search term` or `comment:"your search term"`.
Meaning you can either look for a single word or for a phrase.